# Powershell Hashtable Count and Keys Properties getting overloaded

Tags: powershell, count, key, hashtable

**Problem Statement**:  The Count and Keys properties can get overloaded by a hash value and not return their expected values.

My Powershell Code is this:

```
$hash = @{}
$hash.one = "Number 1"
$hash.two = "Number 2"

"Count is [{0}]" -f $hash.Count
$hash.Count = "Count's Hash Value"
"Count is now [{0}]" -f $hash.Count
```

My Output is this:

```
Count is [2]
Count is now [Count's Hash Value]
```

The Count Property gets overloaded!   This issues could cause users some very hard to diagnose bugs.   Had me confused for a good while.    Same issue applies to "Keys" or in fact any Property.

Do you have any thoughts on best practice to avoid this one? Maybe a different System.Collection?  or prefixing all Keys with a character such as:

```
$key = ":" + $key
```

However, its not very elegant.  Even now that I know the issue, I suspect I will forget and make the same mistake again.

I personally think it is a problem with the Powershell Language Definition.  The . notation (as in $hash.MyKey) should not be allowed for retrieving hash values, only for retrieving Property values.  Just a thought. :-)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can directly call property `get` accessor instead of accessing property or use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```
@{Count=123}.get_Count()
@{Count=123}|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count # does not work on PowerShell Core
```

In PowerShell v3+ you could also use `PSBase` or `PSObject` automatic property:

```
@{Count=123;PSBase=$null}.PSBase.Count
@{Count=123;PSObject=$null}.PSObject.Properties['Count'].Value
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried both your answers.  They both work.  I think I like get_Count() and get_Keys() best.  Syntax is shorter.  This idiosyncrasy with Powershell is potentially dangerous.  I can imagine Customers having intermittent bugs that go undetected for years.

Comment: @Kiwi: For background information, see [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7758).